# How to sequently apply a function on a particular event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

On my current project I am using Bootstrap (3.3.1) standard carousel for testimonials area.  According to the design requirements I have an absolutely positioned section where the actual testimonials (text) should show up. So I have all the testimonials hidden with a special class applied (`.hide_testimo {display: none !important;}`). Here's an example of one of them:

```
<section class="testimonial_holder hide_testimo">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis imperdiet neque ut ex        porttitor tincidunt. Vivamus at efficitur metus.</p>
     <h5 class="testiperson">Linda Plumer <br> <b>Clonix, CTO</b></h5>
</section>
```

What I would like to achieve is to check when the slide (`.item`) gets its 'active' class (i.e. the given slide is shown) and logically remove the testimonials (`.hide_testimo`) to make a particular testimonial visible. So, I'm checking the items with the following piece of jQuery:

```
$('.item').each(function(){
    if ($('.item').hasClass('active')){
     // what's next..?  
    }
})
```

**IMPORTANT:** I didn't mention that the `.item` class is in a different part of the actual markup and it refers to the carousel itself, while `.testimonial_holder` is just an area that is placed above the slider and contains text. Here is the complete markup for better understanding:

```
<div id="testimo_slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <!-- Indicators -->
                        <section class="testimonial_holder show_testimo">
                            <p>"Call you up in the middle of the night
                                like a firefly without a light.
                                You were there like a blowtorch burning
                                I was a key that could use a little turning,
                                so tired that i couldn't even sleep..."</p>
                            <h5 class="testiperson">Janet Aghajanian <br> <b>Lahmajo Systems, CTO</b></h5>
                        </section>
                        <section class="testimonial_holder hide_testimo">
                            <p>"In 1997, Beauty changed my life
                                Who would've known that she would be my future wife
                                or the mother of a child so beautiful
                                see. I had to have them all to be satisfied
                                and on an average night, I'd take four or five"</p>
                            <h5 class="testiperson">Ishita Mehta <br> <b>ORACLE, CSR</b></h5>
                        </section>
                        <section class="testimonial_holder hide_testimo">
                            <p>"Remarkable, incredible, confrontational, yet irreplaceable
                                RAION is fantastic, so I let it go!
                                But it's got the kind of love that you can't let go
                                and still I loved her unconditionally
                                so I wish she had've told me that she didn't love me"</p>
                            <h5 class="testiperson">Monica Lee <br> <b>FAIP Inc., Blogger</b></h5>
                        </section>
                        <section class="testimonial_holder hide_testimo">
                            <p>"Aiyyo whasup kid, feel the rush, glad you kept in touch
                                with RAION, who be puffin on the Dutch
                                bustin guns, lay back in the cut
                                can it be, it's just a dream when you're on your scene.
                                From the streets where life ain't cheap"</p>
                            <h5 class="testiperson">Peter Lancaster <br> <b>TurboTax, Lawyer</b></h5>
                        </section>
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators pagerzz">
                            <li data-target="#testimo_slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#testimo_slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#testimo_slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            <li data-target="#testimo_slider" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                        </ol>

                        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <img src="img/tstmnl_1.jpg" class="img-responsive t_image">
                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="img/tstmnl_2.jpg" class="img-responsive t_image">
                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="img/tstmnl_3.jpg" class="img-responsive t_image">
                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="img/tstmnl_4.jpeg" class="img-responsive t_image">
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to remove the (`.hide_testimo`) class to the testimonial holder sections **sequentially**, so as soon an `.item` becomes active, **only one** testimonial section gets visible and so goes further.

Comment: Why not just do this with CSS?

Comment: Where is the element with class "item"?

Comment: It would help a lot if you would show the relationship between the "item" elements and this `<section>` element.

Comment: I don't understand where's the item class in your example. Do you want to remove hide_testimo from the section element?

Comment: Yes @Pointy, the `.item` is in the carousel markup (I just haven't posted it here in order not to overload the question content). Probably my question is a bit misunderstood and it's my fault since I didn't show that the `.item` is situated in the carousel markup itself while `.testimonial_holder` is a different piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

```
$('#testimo_slider').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (event) {
    var slideIndex = $(event.relatedTarget).index();
    console.log($(event.relatedTarget).index());
    $('.testimonial_holder').each(function(i,val){
        if (i == slideIndex) {
           $(val).removeClass('hide_testimo');
        }
        else {
            $(val).addClass('hide_testimo');
        }
    })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this purely in CSS by taking a different approach. Give your "item" and "testimonial_holder" elements sequential class names like "a", "b", "c", etc. Then when you want to change the active element, you add a class to the outer "testimo_slider" container that controls the layout.

```
        <section class="testimonial_holder a">
            <p>"Call you up in the middle of the night
                like a firefly without a light.
                You were there like a blowtorch burning
                I was a key that could use a little turning,
                so tired that i couldn't even sleep..."</p>
            <h5 class="testiperson">Janet Aghajanian <br> <b>Lahmajo Systems, CTO</b></h5>
        </section>
        <section class="testimonial_holder b">
            <p>"In 1997, Beauty changed my life
                Who would've known that she would be my future wife
                or the mother of a child so beautiful
                see. I had to have them all to be satisfied
                and on an average night, I'd take four or five"</p>
            <h5 class="testiperson">Ishita Mehta <br> <b>ORACLE, CSR</b></h5>
        </section>
        <!-- etc -->

        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item a">
                <img src="img/tstmnl_1.jpg" class="img-responsive t_image">
            </div>

            <div class="item b">
                <img src="img/tstmnl_2.jpg" class="img-responsive t_image">
            </div>

            <!-- etc -->
```

Now you can control the layout with simple CSS and only change classes on the outer container:

```
.carousel .testimonial_holder {
  display: none;
  /* other layout for when the block is not active */
}

.carousel .item {
  /* layout for when "item" block is not active */
}

.carousel.show-a .testimonial_holder.a {
  display: block;
  /* layout for when the block is active */
}

.carousel.show-a .item.a {
  /* for when the "item" blocks are active */
}
```

No need for any `!important` qualifiers; generally, if you think you need `!important`, you should probably start re-thinking what you're doing.

This could get pretty verbose if you have a *lot* of blocks in your carousel, but even then a tool like SCSS or LESS would make it pretty painless.  (For hundreds of blocks you'd probably want to come up with another idea.)

Comment: Thanks for your time and explanation @Pointy. Well, I don't really get what is the `.show-a` class that you've mentioned in the code. And what about `.active` class? The point is that this `.active` is a Bootstrap factory class that is added automatically (via Bootstrap JS) to all the `.item`s as the carousel loops through.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on doing this with JS, the following would suffice.  This solution assumes that the testimonials and their corresponding `.item` elements are in the same order:

```
//Get all of the holders
var holders = $('#testimo_slider .tesimonial_holder');

//Cycle through their corresponding items
$('.carousel-inner .item').each(function(i,v){
    if ($(v).hasClass('active')){
      holders.eq(i).addClass('show_testimo').removeClass('hide_testimo');
    } else {
      holders.eq(i).addClass('hide_testimo').removeClass('show_testimo');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @AlexZ. Actually, the `.item` is in another section of the markup, it's the actual slider part. So I need to build a relation between these two pieces, when `.item` gets `.active`, the `.testimonial_holder` should get rid of its `.hide_testimo` class.

Comment: Erm, ok.  I modified the code to respect that.  I don't really think it changes much...

Comment: Thanks @AlexZ, I've also updated my initial question, so I've pasted the larger scope of the code, so it's easier to get to the point now.

Comment: Ok, the new solution should work, assuming the order of the items matches the order the testimonial sections.  If that can't be guaranteed, you'll need to mark your testimonial sections and items with matching `data-testimonial-index` attributes.